# Scrap info from htm with Beautifulsoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Good morning, i can't find the data correctly with beautifulsoup, can you help me? i want to get the last numbers of this html:
i want to have only the employee id ( 22219 )

```
    <td class="day list-item">
<div class="allocation-day click-area clickable" data-date="2022-02-07" data-url="anonymous-duty-details?beginDate=2022-02-07&amp;allocatedEmployeeId=22219">
<div class="day-info">
<div class="date-with-type">7</div>
<div class="weekday">Mo.</div>
<div class="row-status-icons">
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = ('20105.html')
with open(url, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = bs(contents, features="html.parser")
   
userfinder = soup.find_all('data-url', class_='')
tutte = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"data-url":"data-url"})
print(tutte)

print(tutte)
print(userfinder)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select your targets more specific - In this case `css selectors` are used two select all div with an `attribute` data-url:

```
soup.select('div[data-url]')
```

To get the values from the resultset you have to iterate it:

```
for url in soup.select('div[data-url]'):
    print(url['data-url'])
##output
anonymous-duty-details?beginDate=2022-02-07&allocatedEmployeeId=22219
```

Getting only the ids a simple approache could be to `split()` the url-string, but be aware only if structure is still the same, else you have to use `regex` or other approaches:

```
for url in soup.select('div[data-url]'):
    print(url['data-url'].split('=')[-1])

##output
22219
```

Simple `regex` approache:

```
import re

for url in soup.select('div[data-url]'):
    print(re.search(r"allocatedEmployeeId=(\d*)",url['data-url']).group(1))

##output
22219
```

---

EDIT

Getting only the first result use `select_one()`:

```
soup.select_one('div[data-url]')['data-url'].split('=')[-1]
```

or

```
import re

re.search(r"allocatedEmployeeId=(\d*)",soup.select_one('div[data-url]')['data-url']).group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its working! Hand how i can get only the first result? why ihave several 50 the same result, I only need the first number..

Comment: Answer is based on examples of your question - Added an EDIT to my answer you can use `select_one()` to pick only the first result. Take a look.

Comment: in the first one (with re) i became an error; "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' " And with second example, with select one , I receive as an answer the date and not the number 2022-02-01

Comment: Not able to guess structure and content of your HTML file - Improving the question would be great and lead to more concrete suggestions for solutions. Maybe you won't need `bs4` for this job and `re.search(r"allocatedEmployeeId=(\d*)",contents).group(1)`  will do the job, but this needs further information. Thanks

Comment: Now is working, Thank you very much!